# How to discover other devices on a network programmatically?

Tags: networking, multiplayer

Imagine  you are designing a multiplayer game and would like to host a game. Other players within the same local network can search for opened games and join.

How can that be achieved programmatically?

Here is what I have considered:
   1) Finding the local IP address and do port scan (not feasible with IPv6)
   2) Provide ip-address of the host and let users input it (not good for consumers)

How is such a task normally done? Is that where multicasts come into play? I am looking for solution which can work for both IPv6 and IPv4. Port scanning is simply not good.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: perhaps it would be nice if you explain why you downvoted this. I believe I am asking a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research, it turns out that:

1) For IPv4, you can send a broadcast message to the broadcast address

2) For IPv6, you can send a multicast message.

The router has to not be blocking UDP packets.